# avoid lock and allow two scripts to insert data in one table

Tags: postgresql, locking

I have a database called `db1` and I'm filling it with other two different databases, let's call `db2` and `db3`. I connect db2 and db3 to db1 using `postgres_fdw` and now I'm running scripst like this:

```
insert into db1.table from select a,b,c from db2.table
```

and

```
insert into db1.table from select a,b,c from db3.table
```

turns out that only the first script is running, the second is waiting with `idle in transaction.` This is what `htop` shows me from the second script, while the first is ok.

[image: htop]

looking for reasons, I found out that this may be happening due to a lock, so investigating on postgres, I also found this

[image: lock]

I'm inserting data into `interactions` and each `interactions` has `user`, so I'm selecting the correct user before insert into interaction.
Is there a way to bypass the lock? If so, is it safe?

Comment: The second insert query is blocked while the first one is running? In other words, does the second query start after the first one is completed?

Comment: I don't know exactly because the first query didn't finished ran, but I guess it runs smoothly after the first finishes.

Comment: The seccond query is blocked by the first one because its a single transaction which affects the same table.

You can only READ from a locked table, for `INSERTS` or `UPDATES` you will have to be queued and they will be performed when the lock is gone.

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio I know this, but my question is if there's a way to passthrough this lock

Comment: Short answer is "there is not", here is the long answer http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

You could put both query's into one statement though but they wont run in paralell...

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio: that is wrong. You can update, delete, insert with many transactions on the same table without the transactions blocking each other - provided that each transactions deals with *different* rows. Two inserts will **only** block each other if the second one is trying to insert the same primary key (or unique key) values as the first one. The same is true for updates: you can have as many concurrent updates on a table as there are unique rows (if each transaction updates a single row)

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name but in this examples multiple updates on one table are done by 1 and only 1 transaction. If he had a program doing those UPDATES for him using 1 transaction each then UPDATES and INSERTS will appear to be concurrent but fact is they will be queued by/on the MVCC

Answer (score 3):

`idle in transaction` means it is waiting for data from the client, not that is waiting on a lock.

And your excerpt from pg_lock supports this, assuming the last column is the "granted" column.  All locks have been granted, no one is blocking.

If your scripts are blocking each other, it seems to be happening outside of the database.  Or at least, outside of that particular database.